# How can I see which request caused IIS7 to reset due to a stackoverflow?

Tags: iis-7, logging

My IIS7 webservers are getting hundreds of requests a second, and at a known time a stackoverflow caused IIS7 to recycle the app pool. How can I see which request contained the stackoverflow, and ideally what the stack trace was in that request when IIS decided to kill the app pool?

Comment: I can't remember if it's by default or I changed something, but I get exceptions (and I think a stack trace too) in the event log

Answer (score 1):

How do you know it's a stack overflow? Whatever's reporting this would seem to be reporting that the process crashed.

Get set up for next time - run DebugDiag 1.2 or a crash-mode debugger against the process and get set up for a memory dump on crash.

So in short:

1. Work out the PID of the app pool for the current instance (you might want to turn off recycling so that it doesn't keep changing; or use DebugDiag, which can target an App Pool across PIDs)
2. ADPLUS / PROCDUMP -P PID -CRASH  (or run DebugDiag with a Crash rule for that App Pool)
3. Get the dump file, and feed it into DebugDiag
4. Look for particularly long thread stacks

Comment: the event log says it is a stackoverflow, but otherwise gives no helpful info.

Comment: Posting the event would help everyone trying to help. More diagnostic information is always better than less.